# C++ What is __restrict for and how to use it correctly?

Tags: c++, restrict-qualifier

The `__restrict` in the code below completely unwinds the loop and shortens the assembly by more than a half. But what does it mean and how should it be correctly used?

I did research before asking... I found [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html). But alas, I do not understand it.

```
// Compile with -O3 -march=native to see autovectorization
void maxArray(double* __restrict x, double* __restrict y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 65536; i++) {
        if (y[i] > x[i]) x[i] = y[i];
    }
}
```

[Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Pa7zn56Wh)

Comment: Your code might be seen as C code, and the C standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says something about `restrict`. I do recommend looking inside some C standard. See also [this website](https://en.cppreference.com/w)

Comment: It's definitely C++, the keyword is `__restrict` not the same as `restrict`

Comment: Yes, but the C++ standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) does not mention `__restrict` or `restrict`. It is a [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) language extension documented [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html)

Comment: `__restrict` is a compiler specific extension, that is (more or less) related to the `restrict` keyword in C (C99 and later).   It's purpose is to say that two pointers are not aliased.  In your sample code, it means `x` and `y` point at different things (each is treated as an array with 65535 elements, and those arrays cannot overlap).    Microsoft also support `__restrict` - info at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/extension-restrict?view=msvc-160

Comment: @Peter Can you please elaborate on that? It's just saying that the pointers don't point to the same memory space? Can't the compiler work that out by itself?

Comment: If it gives such a big improvement seems like it'd be good practice to include that everywhere where it's true.

Comment: It is an *annotation* given by the programmer to "promise" than pointers and the pointed memory zones don't "overlap". A good compiler might not be able to *always* deduce that automatically (because of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem)...)

Comment: re: *"Can't the compiler work that out by itself?"* - How can it in a seperate compilation model? That function can be compiled in some object and then linked in a lot of other places. The compiler can't see all of them in advance to choose how the loop is to be treated. It needs that extra information.

Comment: @Alasdair Try to think like a compiler. If you want to process some data using vectorizaion (SIMD) instructions and optimization techniques like loop unrolling, there generally cannot be any dependencies between iterations. Which is basically what `restrict` says. Otherwise, you need to assume that writing into `x[i]` can overwrite `y[i]` in the next iteration.

Comment: @Alasdair -  `restrict` allows the compiler to assume, when compiling the function, to *assume* that the areas of memory will not overlap.   It can then optimise the function accordingly (no need to check for overlaps, no need to reorder to allow for the possibility of overlaps).     When compiling the caller, it requires the compiler to check if the memory overlaps (or, if the caller has been passed the pointers, it requires them to also be `restrict`)

Answer (score 5):

Imagine you declare some `static double array[100000];` then your `main` is calling `maxArray(array, array + 17);`

Without the `restrict` annotation (or [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html)), the compiler is not allowed to *strongly* [unroll the loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) (because the two array slices are overlapping)

With the `restrict` annotation you as a programmer promises that this would never happen (so you won't do `maxArray(array, array + 17);` in such a `main`), and then the compiler can [optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) more agressively

There is a similar difference (for C) between [memcpy](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/string_h/memcpy.php) and [memmove](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/string_h/memmove.php) and an optimizing compiler would generate different code for them.

Be aware of the [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem), which states theoretical limitations related to these issues. A theoretical framework for agressive optimizations could be [abstract interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation).

If you use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (you may look into the generated assembler code produced with `g++ -Wall -O3 -S -fverbose-asm`) **you could** with your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) **and a *lot* of efforts *improve* the optimizations**. You also could use GCC [developer options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html) to understand various optimizations, and since GCC is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), you can study and improve its source code. Budget months of effort for this.

Consider using, if so allowed, static analysis tools for C or C++ code like [Frama-C](https://www.frama-c.com/) or the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

Consider using, in addition of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) and its [watchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html)), if so allowed, dynamic instrumentation techniques like [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) and the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer). They do slow down a lot your executable!